# Alert Json object

Tags: javascript, json

**I have the following json object i need to alert it through javascript.**

```
{data:[{"empmenuid":"1","empid":null,"deptid":"66","aliasid":"66","firstname":"66","lastname":"66","sin":"66","status":"66","empclass":"66","hiredate":"66","seneoritydate":"66","separationdate":"66","recalldate":"66","martialstatus":"66","gender":"66","ethinicorigin":"66","ethinicsuborigin":"66","nationality":"66","address1":"66","address2":"66","city":"66","province":"66","postalcode":"66","country":"66","email":"66","officialemail":"66","phone":"66","otherphone":"66","fax":"66","officephone":"66","officeext":"66","officefax":"66","mobilephone":"66","pager":"66","locid":"66","jobtitle":"66","jobtitlestart":"66","fullpart":"66","manager":"66","managername":"66","middlename":"66","nickname":"66","paytype":"66","payfreq":"66"},{"empmenuid":"3","empid":null,"deptid":"12","aliasid":"12","firstname":"12","lastname":"12","sin":"12","status":"12","empclass":"12","hiredate":"12","seneoritydate":"12","separationdate":"12","recalldate":"12","martialstatus":"12","gender":"12","ethinicorigin":"12","ethinicsuborigin":"12","nationality":"12","address1":"12","address2":"12","city":"121","province":"12","postalcode":"12","country":"12","email":"12","officialemail":"12","phone":"12","otherphone":"12","fax":"12","officephone":"12","officeext":"12","officefax":"12","mobilephone":"12","pager":"12","locid":"12","jobtitle":"12","jobtitlestart":"12","fullpart":"12","manager":"12","managername":"12","middlename":"12","nickname":"12","paytype":"12","payfreq":"12"}],
recordType : 'object'}
```

Answer (score 101, accepted):

Just use

```
alert(JSON.stringify(your_json_obj));
```

Answer (score 8):

You can access a JSON objects properties using the `dot` operator:

```
var person {
   "name":"test",
   "age":20    
}

//document.write(person.name);
alert(person.name);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use **console.log** instead

Comment: i used consol.log and firebug shows me the above mentioned data.But when i alert it,it only alerts object.

Comment: alert shows me something like as follows,

[{"empmenuid":"3","empid":null,"deptid":"12","aliasid":"12","firstname":"12","lastname":"12","sin":"12","status":"12","empclass":"12","hiredate":"12","seneoritydate":"12","separationdate":"12","recalldate":"12","martialstatus":"12","gender":"12","ethinicorigin":"12","ethinicsuborigin":"12" ............"}]


Now i want to get empmenuid from this, i used myJSONText.empmenuid but it says "UNDEFINED".

Comment: It is because it is a string now. It need to be a object to call like that, which means you call myJSON.empmenuid before JSON.stringify. Alternativ is that you convert it back with Jquery function "jQuery.parseJSON"

Answer (score 0):

To see properly formated data in alert pop,
one approach could be.

```
alert(JSON.stringify(YOUR_OBJECT_HERE, null, 4));
```

if we have stringified object

```
alert(JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(STRIGYFIED_DATA, null, 4)));
```

Answer (score -4):

```
var  obj = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": {
      "street": "Kulas Light",
      "suite": "Apt. 556",
      "city": "Gwenborough",
      "zipcode": "92998-3874",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-37.3159",
        "lng": "81.1496"
      }
    },
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crova",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": {
      "street": "Victor Plains",
      "suite": "Suite 879",
      "city": "Wisokyburgh",
      "zipcode": "90566-7771",
      "geo": {
        "lat": "-43.9509",
        "lng": "-34.4618"
      }
    },
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  }];
alert( obj.????? ) ;
```

Comment: your answer is not formatted and also does not solve the OP's problem.